# Missing exception log on /actuator/prometheus when returning 404

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I have a Spring Boot microservice, which uses the Micrometer libary for instrumentation. I forgot to add micrometer-registry-prometheus which resulted in a 404 status code when requesting /actuator/prometheus.

The issue here is that no error message or exception was displayed in the log output.

Is there a way to configure the log output in a way that Spring Boot prints an error log or exception if it tries to load a missing library?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might have overlooked enabling the actuator endpoint. To resolve this, you can enable it by incorporating the following properties:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Comment: The question is not about how to enable the prometheus endpoint. It's about why spring-boot does not log an exception if the micrometer library is not present.